# Issues in Connecting USB DEVICES to AMAZON APPSTREAM2.0

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, aws-appstream

I am currently using AWS AppStream 2.0 to stream a desktop application. For this, I need to connect my local devices to the AppStream 2.0 and use them with the streamed application. For enabling USB Devices I have followed the procedure given in the AWS documentation but couldn't get the device to work.

Link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appstream2/latest/developerguide/qualify-usb-devices.html

I tried with two webcams, one of the camera is detected as Imaging Device and is enabled but couldn't deliver any frames. The other camera is enabled in the AppStream but is not detected as an Imaging Device and shown as a USB.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In general, there could be several reasons why you was not able to use the device.

- As in the documentation in your post, you need to whitelist the correct device id.
- Also you need to install the required driver on AppStream.
- This feature is only supported with the native windows client for AppStream.

However, for you special need (the Webcam), there is good news, AWS recently launched native webcam support, therefore there is no need to do this workaround with USB.